# How to loop through fields in a Express req.send to build form data?

Tags: javascript, express

I have [code](https://github.com/unee-t/s3-transfer-acceleration-cloudinary/blob/aws-sdk/app.js#L75-L80) that looks like:

```
res.send(`
        fd.append('policy', '${presigned.fields.Policy}');
        fd.append('X-Amz-Signature', "${presigned.fields['X-Amz-Signature']}");
        fd.append('X-Amz-Credential', "${presigned.fields['X-Amz-Credential']}");
        fd.append('X-Amz-Algorithm', "${presigned.fields['X-Amz-Algorithm']}");
        fd.append('X-Amz-Date', "${presigned.fields['X-Amz-Date']}");
        fd.append('X-Amz-Security-Token', "${presigned.fields['X-Amz-Security-Token']}")
`)
```

But what I need to do is loop through the `presigned.fields` since some may be present or missing depending on its running context. and create the form data. How do people sanely generate the client side Javascript to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons I would verify parameters server side. Also if some of those params land in a database check for sql injection.

```
var _params = {
 name: 'doe',
 pass: 'abc'
};

for (var _key in _params) {
  var _this_value = _params[_key];

  if (_key === 'name') {
    //do some check on name
    console.log(_this_value);
  }

  if (_key === 'pass') {
    //do some check on password
    console.log(_this_value);
  }
}
```